# How to access directory file outside django project?

Tags: python, django, apache, httpd.conf

I have my Django project running on RHEL 7 OS. The project is in path `/root/project`. And project is hosted on httpd server. Now iam trying to access a file out side the directory like `/root/data/info/test.txt`

How should I access this path in views.py so that I can read and write file which is outside the project directory ? I tried to add the path in `sys.path` but it didn't work. Read and write permission are also give to the file.

Comment: Did you try "../data/info/test.txt" ?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path?

Comment: Why would you want to do something outside a project directory? I mean choose to `read/write a file inside the project directory` (create the file if it's not present) and for your git/svn (Version control system), `ignore the file from getting committed` to the project

Comment: Yes. I tried with full path which gives we 500 internal error. ......... Iam trying to do some automation which have a common repository from where the other user can get the data and run the script. This shared directory i donot want to me in project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `settings.py`

```
import os
..
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FILES_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../data/info'))
```

Then you can use in your view

```
from django.conf import settings
import os
..
file_path = os.path.join(settings.FILES_DIR, 'test.txt')
```