# Django write to csv in views not working

Tags: python, django, csv

In my views I have:

```
import csv 
outputfile = open("test.csv", 'w')
```

I am getting a `[Errno 13] Permission Denied`

So I tried just opening the file:

```
outputfile = open("test.csv")
```

I am getting a `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.csv'` when I try to open it.

When I run the same line of code using `python manage.py shell`, the file opens without an error. `test.csv` is in the same folder as my views.

Why am I getting these errors and how do I go about fixing them?

Comment: try using fullpath, most likely it has a different working directory when you run within the view.

Comment: Tried it. The same errors are being thrown at me

Comment: Where do you want to save it? And with that user ?, Do you have write permissions on that folder?

Comment: Try printing out os.getcwd() after importing the os module. You should also check the file's user rights and ownership.

Comment: I had a sort of similar problem. Put the csv file in the app folder that has the view and try again. Should work

Comment: alternatively : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228449/how-to-access-directory-file-outside-django-project
Try reading that